# Need tool to format html (indent, add whitespace)

Tags: c#, .net, html, formatting, indentation

I am working on a .net project that generates html.

When the html string is generated, the is no whitespace or indenting. This makes understanding the generated html difficult.

Is there a tool that will take my string of generated html and format it so that it looks nice?

Comment: What's generating the html?  is HtmlTextWriter an option?

Comment: Do you mean an automated, or a manual tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're generating the HTML yourself, it should be valid XML.

Therefore, you can use the `XDocument` class to format it.

You can build the HTML inside an `XDocument`, then call `ToString()`, which will automatically format the HTML for you.

In addition, XDocument should be much easier to use than manual string concatenation, and will intrinsically protect you from most (but not all) XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [online version of Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/)

Comment: Saved my life, been looking for something like this for hours!

Answer (score 2):

using https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(html);

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    document.ToHtml(writer, new PrettyMarkupFormatter());
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in taking a look at Tidy, http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTMLTextWriter and call HTMLTextWriter.Indent to set the indention of the lines.