# I want to code the HTML syntax indented and colored like in Visual Studio editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

**App:** Let's take an asp.net mvc 3 app.

**Scope:** To add an HTML Editor and most of them have 2-3 tabs: *Design, HTML* and *Preview* modes.

**Result expected:** When I design in design mode, the generated syntax of HTML markup **Should appear indented and colored** so it would be easy to edit and read if there is a lot of elements and attributes.

**Examples** of WYSIWYG HTML editors that I think about are: TinyMce; DXperience 2011 vol II MVC extension - HTMLEditor; CLEditor;

So **Question is:** How to obtain the generated Html Syntax indented and colored? the perfect result is like in Visual Studio editor of aspx or view pages. 
    So, what you think about it geeks ? :) Appreciate that!

Comment: yes Html Source mode. It should be generated Indented or highlighted like in notepad++ e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Well for code highlighting/coloring, many sites are using Alex Gorbatchev's syntax highligher.

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter

For indentation - you can use XDocument's ToString() as outlined here:

[Need tool to format html (indent, add whitespace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172174/need-tool-to-format-html-indent-add-whitespace)